# how can I draw chart like this image with JS or some library

Tags: javascript, charts, geometry

how can I draw chart like this image with JS or some library

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AoYy.png][1]

Answer (score 0):

Your chart looks like a Bubble Chart to me. While there are lot other options to draw similar chart you want to draw, I would suggest to look at somewhere it's already done. Just have a look at D3.js example of bubble chart here 
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269